# Invalid Column Name NA

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to get the following insert statement to work but I have had no luck. I've researched and tried many things but haven't found a solution. Is there anyway to assign the literal string NA to the column?

```
qryALL (@pPK BIGINT,@pAL FLOAT,@pFK BIGINT)
AS
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tblTPF ( fldFPK, fldPK, fldDTA, fldCI, fldMD, fldME, 
fldIQ, fldSD, fldND, fldNI, fldNL, fldMI, fldMA, fldUN, fldAV )
SELECT '+ Convert(varchar,@pFK) +' AS sFPK, '+ Convert(varchar,@pPK) +' AS sPK, 
GETDATE() AS sDate, '+ Convert(varchar,@pAL) +' AS sAL, -254 AS sMD, -254 AS sME,
-254 AS sIQ, -254 AS sSD, 0 AS sND, 0 AS sNI, 0 AS sNL, -254 AS sMI, -254 AS sMA, 
NA AS sUN, 0 AS sAV;'

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: [Please stop declaring `varchar` without length. I promise this will break something for you at some point](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Literal strings should be enclosed into single quotation marks, e.g. `select 'NA' as sUN`, and literal string inside string should be enclosed into doubled single quotation marks:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tblTPF ( fldFPK, fldPK, fldDTA, fldCI, fldMD, fldME, 
fldIQ, fldSD, fldND, fldNI, fldNL, fldMI, fldMA, fldUN, fldAV )
SELECT '+ Convert(varchar,@pFK) +' AS sFPK, '+ Convert(varchar,@pPK) +' AS sPK, 
GETDATE() AS sDate, '+ Convert(varchar,@pAL) +' AS sAL, -254 AS sMD, -254 AS sME,
-254 AS sIQ, -254 AS sSD, 0 AS sND, 0 AS sNI, 0 AS sNL, -254 AS sMI, -254 AS sMA, 
''NA'' AS sUN, 0 AS sAV;'
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but I guess not. Anyways it's working, thank you!